# How can I achieve this using HighCharts library

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am very new to `Highcharts`. I am developing a dashboard and I need to create a percentage usage of equipment at a Plant. I checked all the demos provided by `Highcharts` but didn't find a similar one.

This what I need.

[image]

I know I can do it from scratch but I prefer to use `Highcharts` if possible.

Comment: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-stacked looks like a starting point to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prepared a demo with using `stacked bar` which could be a good point start for you to create a same chart as in the shared picture.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qum72ejL/

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'bar'
  },

  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  legend: {
    reversed: true
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{y} %'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Other',
    data: [11]
  }, {
    name: 'Dust Collection',
    data: [26]
  }, {
    name: 'Compressed Air',
    data: [17]
  }, {
    name: 'Vacuum System',
    data: [34]
  }, {
    name: 'Chillers',
    data: [12]
  }]
});
```

Comment: how can I hide the word `values` under the xAxis? I can hide it using css but is there a way to hide it through the Json values? I tried to set text to `null` and disabled `legends` but didn't work

Comment: @AliAlAmine for the `bar` series the axes are reversed, that's mean that this axis with the `values` title is a yAxis. Here is a demo which shows how to disable title: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z85myx9w/ API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.title.enabled

Comment: can you help out with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322181/how-to-integrate-data-to-spline-chart-highcharts