# how to integrate data to Spline chart | Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, spline

I am very new to Highcarts and I am trying to implement a `spline` chart with two curves using `Highcharts` library.

The first curve represents `Today` data, the second curve represents the `Past 7 days`.

the xAxis categories are `['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Th', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']`
and the yXais the data between 10 and 150.

I will provide a very specific example so anyone can easily understand how it works. I want to understand how the `Today` and `Past 7 days` data (date and value) integrated with xAxis and yAxis.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/36pv4fjs/53/

below is the chart configuration:

```
{
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
        },
        xAxis: {
            labels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            categories: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Th', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series:
            [
                {
                    name: 'Today',
                    data: todayData
                },
                {
                    name: 'Past 7 days',
                    data: past7dats,
                    color: 'lightgreen'
                }
            ]
    }
```

The Today data are: (time date is constant for all)

```
[
    {"time":"2020-10-12T00:00:00+03:00","value":12},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T00:15:00+03:00","value":13},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T00:30:00+03:00","value":20},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T00:45:00+03:00","value":25},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T01:00:00+03:00","value":20},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T01:15:00+03:00","value":30},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T01:30:00+03:00","value":20},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T01:45:00+03:00","value":25},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T02:00:00+03:00","value":30},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T02:15:00+03:00","value":40},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T02:15:00+03:00","value":20},
    {"time":"2020-10-12T02:15:00+03:00","value":35}
]
```

The past 7 days data are: (time date is for the past 7 days)

```
[
    {"time":"2020-10-12T00:00:00+03:00","value":35},
    {"time":"2020-10-11T00:15:00+03:00","value":30},
    {"time":"2020-10-10T00:30:00+03:00","value":20},
    {"time":"2020-10-09T01:00:00+03:00","value":25},
    {"time":"2020-10-08T01:15:00+03:00","value":30},
    {"time":"2020-10-07T01:30:00+03:00","value":40},
    {"time":"2020-10-06T00:45:00+03:00","value":35},

]
```

Comment: Take a look at how your data looks like after parsing it: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e1vnL4gf/ How do you want to compare this data? Are you able to share some pictures of the wanted result? And here is also a demo without the `x values` as an date format: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/624gf7m1/ Which one is correct to you?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel This cleared up the matter, Actually I wanted to know about these two ways, but still need to know how to configure the tool tip so when hovering over the chart user would be able to see the readable time and the values

Comment: You can use the `tooltip.formatter` callback to customize what the tooltip displays. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter Or a `pointFormat`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat